# Rescaling 300 polygons within one shapefile, but keeping original center position of each polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, scale

I have a shapefile type Fishnet in ArcMap, containing 300 or so polygons in it.
Each polygon represent an area of interest containing plants. I have a model extracting the zonal stats of the shapefile for each of the polygons.
I want to reduce the size of each polygon where they are, without changing their positions.
If I use the scale option after selecting several of my polygons, it will move the little cross midway between all these selected polygons. And when the size change, the polygons will increase or decrease in size but will become farer or closer respectively.
Globally, when I select different polygon, I want each of them having the cross in them signaling the center, and resize around each of these cross, where they were originally.

Any ideas?

I have tried to use "Buffer". However, it was not working on using negative values, and when I tried using positive values to see if it can work in increasing the size of the polygons, it was only drafting a circle above my polygon, and bigger than it.
so it is not the tool that I need.

I remember having used one in the past, but impossible to remember which one. I was having 1600 circles on my "fishnet" grid. They were supposed to be positions of plants of interest in field.
And a tool allowed me to decrease by a ratio all the circles at once while keeping each of those in place (just a smaller radius that they have had before)

Comment: Try Buffer with a negative buffer distance. You might get round corners (not sure), if so then use Minimum bounding geometry after buffer

Comment: Is it the same reduction or depends on a value stored in its table?

Comment: same reduction for all polygons. lets say, all reduced by 50% from original size, but keeping original centroid location

Comment: Negative buffer should work, if it doesn't it could be from a unit problem (check your crs unit).  An alternative is to get your polygon centroid then buffer the centroid then as BERA said use minimum bounding geometry to get back to square....